# can say every group that satisfy in maximal permutizer condition then satisfy then permutizer condition

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

The
permutizer of a subgroup $H$ of $G$ is defined to be the subgroup generated by all cyclic subgroups of $G$ that permute with $H$,
i.e. $\langle x \in G | \langle x \rangle H = H \langle x \rangle \rangle $, denoted by $P_G(H)$.

A group $G$ is said to satisfy the permutizer condition in $G$ if $P_G(H)$ strictly contains $H$ for any subgroup $H$ of $G$.

A group $G$ is said to satisfy the maximal permutizer condition if $P_G(M) = G$ for any maximal subgroup $M$
of $G$.

Now can say every group that satisfy in maximal permutizer condition then satisfy then permutizer condition ?